# Strip version number from dependency based on group ID in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a project that has 3rd party dependencies, as well as dependencies on internal projects. I need to strip the version numbers from the dependent artifacts that are developed in-house.

For example: `spring-2.5.6.jar` should be in the final output as `spring-2.5.6.jar` but `MyInternalProject-1.0.17.jar` needs to be changed to `MyInternalProject.jar`.

I can identify the internal dependencies easily enough by their group ID (they are all something like `com.mycompany.*`). The `maven-dependency-plugin` has a `stripVersion` option, but it does not seem to be selective enough. Is there a way to do this, short of explicitly naming each dependency and what their final name should be?

---

Phrased another way:

I would like to have different `outputFileNameMapping`s for the maven-assembly-plugin for artifacts based on group ID. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can I ask *why* you want to strip the versions of some artifacts?

Comment: What do you mean with "final output" Some assembly, .war, .zip, .ear?

Comment: @GyroGearless: It's a zip archive.

Comment: So do you just want the zip file to not have the version? Or you want the jar files included in the zip that were built from internal artifacts not to have versions either?

Comment: @JeffStorey: The reason I was given was that eventually, the archive will be unzipped and the jars and files within will be checked into source control. They'd like to have revision history for the internally developed jars, so the filenames cannot have version numbers in them. 3rd party jars change much less frequently and they'd rather have version numbers in the filename so they can see what version of the jar they are using.

Comment: @JeffStorey: The in-house artifacts in the zip file should not have version numbers, the 3rd party artifacts in the zip file should have version numbers. For the zip file itself, it probably doesn't matter (but I know how to control that already if I need to).

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I think that approach may have some issues ... I'll post my full answer with details

Comment: I suppose you are using the maven-assembly-plugin to eventually make your .zip?

Comment: I suppose you can do this be defining custom mappings in your assembly descriptor - see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_file . Unfortunately, i have no example at hand, can check this at work tomorrow. (setting `source` and `destName` should do the trick)

Comment: @GyroGearless: Yes, I'd already played around with `outputFileNameMapping`. The problem is that it applies to all artifacts, I want to apply different mappings based on different artifact group IDs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can using the following recipe:

First, in your aggregator pom use the `dependency:copy-dependencies` goal to copy your jars to some intermediate location. You will need two executions, one with `<stripVersion>true</stripVersion>` for your internal dependencies; and one with `<stripVersion>false</stripVersion>` for 3rd party libraries. You may include/exclude artifacts based on GroupId, see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html for full details.

Then it should be a simple task to build a .zip using the maven-assembly-plugin!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I would re-evaluate your approach here. Generally checking jars into source control is not a good idea, especially unversioned jars. Imagine if I just had a project that referenced *someArtifact.jar* and I was trying to debug it - how would I know which version it used?

Tools like artifactory and nexus were built for storing versions of your jars, both internal and 3rd party (they can also proxy public repositories like maven central). In order to keep builds reproducible, I would check your binaries into a tool designed for that, and then you can reference them by version. During development, you can reference SNAPSHOT versions of your jars to get the latest, and then when you do a release, you can reference stable versions of your binaries.

Source control systems were meant for storing source, not binaries.

Comment: I agree. This was not my decision. I suspect that once we show that Maven can get artifacts from repositories automatically (we are very early into the process of Mavenising our projects - there is resistnce to this change), those who want this may loosen up a little. But right now, they are still insistent on having dependencies in source control, without version numbers so that they can trace the history. I agree it's not an ideal setup, but we're trying to ease them into working with Maven gently.

Comment: I don't understand "without version numbers so that they can trace the history" - wouldn't that make it difficult to trace the history?

Comment: If I check in three files named `MyJar-1.0.0.jar`, `MyJar-1.0.1.jar`, and `MyJar-1.0.2.jar`, there will be three distinct files in source control. If I check in each one file `MyJar.jar` three times (each time a newer version), there will be a single file in version control, and a user can see a file history for the file, showing each check-in. Also, there's no integration between source control and Maven. :(

Comment: That's going to really bog down your source control too since binary files can't be diffed. I'd strongly advise that even if you're just introducing maven you at introduce it being used correctly...

Comment: @JeffStorey: Although you are completely right, it might take time to overcome established CM practises, especially in big companys...

Comment: Understood. Can't say I know of an easy way to do what it is you're trying to do though, sorry.